# System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'project_nbr' does not exist in the results

Tags: sql, linq

**We are getting this exception randomly, while googling i found that this could be due to framework issue ... like service packs and all....**

**Below is the Generic Function from where the LINQ TO SQL query is fired / executed**

```
Public Shared Function Find(Of T As ActiveRecordBase)(ByVal id As Object) As ActiveRecordBase

        Dim tableMetaData As MetaTable = GetTableMetadata(Of T)()

        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE {1} = ?", tableMetaData.TableName, GetPrimaryKeyName(Of T))
        sql = sql.Replace("?", "{0}")

        Return UnitOfWork.Current.ExecuteQuery(Of T)(sql, id).FirstOrDefault()
  End Function
```

**This is the Function from where it is called ...**

```
Public Shared Shadows Function Find(ByVal id As Integer) As Project
        Return CType(ActiveRecordBase.Find(Of Project)(id), Project)

End Function
```

> Following Exception thrown
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'project_nbr' does not exist in the results.
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderBase`1.GetColumnOrdinals(NamedColumn[] namedColumns)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderBase`1..ctor(ObjectReaderSession`1 session, NamedColumn[] namedColumns, Object[] globals, Object[] arguments, Int32 nLocals)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderSession`1.CreateReader[TObject](Func`2 fnMaterialize, NamedColumn[] namedColumns, Object[] globals, Int32 nLocals, Boolean disposeDataReader)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReaderFactory`2.Create(DbDataReader dataReader, Boolean disposeDataReader, IReaderProvider provider, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(Object instance, MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.ExecuteQuery[TResult](String query, Object[] parameters)
>      at GeneralMills.P2.ProjectTracking.Domain.ActiveRecordBase.Find[T](Object id)
>      at GeneralMills.P2.ProjectTracking.Domain.Project.Find(Int32 id)
>      at GeneralMills.P2.ProjectTracking.Web.ProjectContext.GetCurrentDomainObject(Int32 key)
>      at GeneralMills.P2.ProjectTracking.Web.ContextBase.GetCurrentItem()
>      at GeneralMills.P2.ProjectTracking.Web.BaseContextPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the column `project_nbr` doesn't exist in the table that is being queried in these cases? Dynamic SQL is a whole heap of hidden dangers. It would be *really* useful if you could prove the SQL that was executed that produced this problem.